# $|\sin(x/n)| \leq x/n$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to follow a proof of calculating a nasty limit using the Dominated Convergence Theorem and the proof asserts (without proof) that $| \sin(x/n)|\leq x/n$ for $x > 0$. This claim is critical in finding the dominating function, but I cannot see how to prove it for the life of me. Any ideas on how to prove this claim?

Comment: You have $|\sin(x)|\le x$ for all $x\ge 0$. However, I love your nick.

Comment: @amsmath hell yea. also inequality is strict for $x>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have this by convexity:

> $$
> \lvert \sin x\rvert \leq x
> $$ for all $x\geq 0$.

Since $f=\sin$ is concave* on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, for $0\leq x\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
$$
 f(x) \leq f(0)+f'(0)x
$$
i.e.
$$
\lvert \sin x\rvert  = \sin x \leq 0 + \cos(0)x = x\,.
$$
For $x>\frac{\pi}{2}$, this is trivial as $\lvert \sin x\rvert  \leq x$ for all $x$.

---

$*$ for instance, by observing that $\sin'' = -\sin\leq 0$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.